# Three.js: Standard Camera Views and FitAll Function

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js

I am currently discovering three.js. I have a problem regarding the standard camera views. My goal is to load multiple Object3D() into my scene, get the whole bounding box of the inserted Object3D() and fit the whole bounding box into the screen (like a "Zoom All" function). I also want to make the standard camera views available (top, bottom, right, left, front, perspective).

A running version can be found on [this site](http://www.lanheadquarters.at/test/).

I read a lot about those things here on stack overflow and other sites on the internet, but it seems that I don't get the concept behind it.
Currently I have multiple camera objects in my scene, which are defined for the necessary views:

```
   function ChangeCam( direction )
    {
        getBBoxValues(scene);

        var bbox;
        bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(scene,0xff0000);
        bbox.update();

        camera = CreateCam(direction, bbox );
        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);

        controls.addEventListener('change', render);
    }

    function CreateCam( direction, elembbox )
    {
        var bbox = elembbox.box;

        switch( direction )
        {
            case "Iso":
                // Camera name: iso_cam 
                var camera_obj = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1000,  500000);

                camera_obj.position.x = (elembbox.position.x + (bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x) * 0.5) * -1;
                camera_obj.position.y = (elembbox.position.x + (bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x) * 0.5) * -1;
                camera_obj.position.z = elembbox.position.x + (bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x) * 0.5;
                camera_obj.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);

                var target = new THREE.Vector3(elembbox.position.x, bbox.min.y + (bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x) * 0.5, elembbox.position.z);
                camera_obj.lookAt(target);

                fitAll(elembbox);

                return camera_obj;
                break;

            case "Top":
                // Camera name: top_cam
                var camera_obj = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2843.14990,  1221700.65039);
                camera_obj.position.x = 0;
                camera_obj.position.y = 0;
                camera_obj.position.z = 5897.56250;
                camera_obj.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
                var target = new THREE.Vector3(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
                camera_obj.lookAt(target);
                return camera_obj;
                break;

            case "Left":
                // Camera name: lft_cam
                var camera_obj = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2843.14990,  17235.64063);
                camera_obj.position.x = 7152.06055;
                camera_obj.position.y = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.position.z = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                var target = new THREE.Vector3(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
                camera_obj.lookAt(target);
                return camera_obj;
                break;

            case "Right":
                // Camera name: rgt_cam
                var camera_obj = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1377.38940,  11372.59961);
                camera_obj.position.x = -7152.06006;
                camera_obj.position.y = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.position.z = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                var target = new THREE.Vector3(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
                camera_obj.lookAt(target);
                return camera_obj;
                break;

            case "Front":
                // Camera name: frt_cam
                var camera_obj = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2198.64063,  16376.29688);
                camera_obj.position.x = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.position.y = -6292.71484;
                camera_obj.position.z = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                var target = new THREE.Vector3(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
                camera_obj.lookAt(target);
                return camera_obj;
                break;

            case "Back":
                // Camera name: bck_cam
                var camera_obj = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 2198.64063,  16376.29590);
                camera_obj.position.x = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.position.y = 6292.71484;
                camera_obj.position.z = 0.00000;
                camera_obj.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
                var target = new THREE.Vector3(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
                camera_obj.lookAt(target);
                return camera_obj;
                break;
        }
    }
```

All cameras (except "ISO") are defined for one predefined Object3D(). There the standard views are working. When I change the cameras values according to the midpoint of the scene bounding box, everything messes up. Maybe there is also a better way with only one camera object?

For the "Zoom All" function I am currently using this, which is not giving me the results I want:

```
function fitAll(bbox)
{
    // create an helper
    helper = bbox;

    // get the bounding sphere
    var boundingSphere = helper.box.getBoundingSphere();

    // calculate the distance from the center of the sphere
    // and subtract the radius to get the real distance.
    var center = boundingSphere.center;
    var radius = boundingSphere.radius;
    var distance = center.distanceTo(camera.position);
    var realHeight = Math.abs(helper.box.max.y - helper.box.min.y);
    var fov = 2 * Math.atan( ( realHeight / (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight) ) / ( 2 * distance )) * ( 180 / Math.PI );

    camera.fov = fov;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help me with this.

Greets

Comment: could you do a jsfiddle if possible

Comment: I think I can't do that as there are too much dependencies. I uploaded the running version to my webserver, maybe that helps? http://www.lanheadquarters.at/test/

Comment: @ms_dos, I am struggling to get the same. See how I created a jsfiddle with my three.js code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ph0ropg7/9/. Perhaps it helps.